# If $A$ is an associative k-algebra, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero, then why $A\bigotimes _{k} k[[t]]\cong A[[t]]$ as a $k[[t]]$ module?

Tags: modules

Here $k[[t]]$ is the $k$-algebra of formal power series and $A[[t]]$ is a $k[[t]]$-module of formal power series.

Comment: Can you prove that the "obvious" mapping is a homomorphism of $k[[t]]$-modules? By the way, you should not rely on the title of your post to be the question. Check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: I.e trivial...I want to know why has an inverse. By the way, I am sorry for not making the title according to the guidelines

Comment: All you want to show is that it is a bijection and that is a $k[[t]]$-homomorphism. For the bijective part you can also consider it as a morphism of $k$ vector spaces. Picking a $k$-basis of $A$ would also be helpful.

Comment: I would think that the image of the canonical map $A \otimes_k k[[t]] \to A[[t]]$ would only consist of the formal series where the span of the coefficients (as a $k$-vector space) is finite dimensional.  So in particular, if $A$ itself is finite dimensional, then the result would hold, but otherwise I don't think it would.

Comment: Thanks a lot Severin. I am quite fine with it. Sorry for delayed reply.